# How to include nodejs package into the script

Tags: node.js

I have faced a very simple problem. I want to use a pakcage named `Rbush` in my javascript script in nodejs.
I have installed it using `npm install rbush` command and when I try to use it It raises this error

```
ReferenceError: RBush is not defined
```

here is my code

```
const t=require('rbush');

 const tree = new RBush();
const item = {
  minX: 20,
  minY: 40,
  maxX: 30,
  maxY: 50,
  foo: 'bar'
};
tree.insert(item);
```

I know that I have to include it into my script and I have done that using `require` function but it seems that it does not add the library there.I also tried the following method but it still does not work.

```
const tree=require('rbush');
const item = {
  minX: 20,
  minY: 40,
  maxX: 30,
  maxY: 50,
  foo: 'bar'
};
tree.insert(item);
```

Comment: This is one of those cases where [asking on the issue tracker](https://github.com/mourner/rbush/issues/97) is far more useful to the rest of the world than asking on Stackoverflow. Unless you were going to file a PR against rbush after getting an answer here, of course.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks Mike, I wanted to ask there but I thought it is more general question with adding nodejs package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node modules export different types, so it's important to check the docs and see what you 'get' when you `require` the module. The usage docs for `rbush` are not great in this respect, but it exports a class, so your first example is almost correct.

The variable you assign the module to is how you need to reference it in your code. So instead of assigning `require('rbush')` to `t`, you probably want to assign it to `RBush`. (You can name it whatever you want, but if you're going to call `new RBush()`, then you need to use that name when you require it, `const RBush = require('rbush');`

```
const RBush = require('rbush');

const tree = new RBush();
const item = {
  minX: 20,
  minY: 40,
  maxX: 30,
  maxY: 50,
  foo: 'bar'
};
tree.insert(item);
```